# Android Studio build error! duplicated R.java file

Tags: java, android

When I try to build and run my application on android, occasionally error message bursts out(already four or five times). When I looked up all error message, it seemed it was a problem of auto-generated R.java files. Somehow, program made R.java files again with the name R 2.java or R 3.java etc. So error message was something like(not exactly same) "error: duplicate class: androidx.asynclayoutinflater.R" and the other one was "R is public class, you need to match file name with class name". When I erased all those files, it worked. But I don't want to encounter that error message again. How can I solve this problem fundamentally?

Comment: have you already fixed it?